# Treating the edges of a div like a JS window object

Tags: javascript, animation, html, canvas

I'm new to Javascript, HTML, and CSS. I read through [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Blando/E3X78/) for a Matrix animation (it's not mine).

The animation lies within the canvas in the HTML:

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

The animation uses the edges of the window to determine when to reset the "drops":

```
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;
```

I want the animation to instead detect the edges of a `div` that I would put around the canvas like this:

```
 <div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I change the `window.innerHeight` to an object representing the `div`, so that I can re-size the animation by simply altering the dimensions of the `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give DIV an ID, for example `<div id='container'>` then you can do

```
c.height = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;
c.width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E3X78/1/

Comment: Worked like a charm, I have another question, though: Is this attaching a method onto another method? And is this common?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by attaching a method. `getElementById` is a common browser function to get a DOM object and `offsetWidth/offsetHeight` are common properties of a DOM object. So yes, pretty much this approach is very common.

Comment: I understand. I guess I just haven't had enough experience to see anything more than OBJECT.METHOD. Thank you